# Cómo puedo calcular el IVA de un valor para insertarlo en una tabla?

Tags: sql, trigger, plsql, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

tengo una consulta muy específica, poseo una tabla llamada OC en donde se insertan órdenes de compra de distintos productos. En dicha tabla tengo dos campos, uno de ellos es 'neto' y el otro 'impuesto'.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces necesito crear un Trigger (o alguna función) que, al momento de insertar valores en la tabla OC, calcule el impuesto que sería el valor (neto)*19/100. Estoy un poco complicado con esto, agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Por principio no deberías almacenar cálculos; y en tal caso deberías primero considerar una *columna virtual* antes que un disparador, y antes que una función.

Answer (score 0):

--Si el valor neto es 500€
--El impuesto es el 19%

--En el mismo momento del INSERT:

```
v_neto := 500;
v_impuesto := 19;

INSERT (ID_OC, NUMERO_DOCUMENTO, /*DEMÁS COLUMNAS OBLIGATORIAS*/, NETO, IMPUESTO) 
  VALUES (1, 1, /*DEMÁS VALORES OBLIGATORIOS*/, v_neto, (v_neto * v_impuesto)/100);
```

Con una función:

```
v_neto := 500;
v_impuesto := 19;

INSERT (ID_OC, NUMERO_DOCUMENTO, /*DEMÁS COLUMNAS OBLIGATORIAS*/, NETO, IMPUESTO) 
  VALUES (1, 1, /*DEMÁS VALORES OBLIGATORIOS*/, v_neto, calcula_neto(v_neto, v_impuesto));

FUNCTION calcula_neto
 (P_IMPORTE  NUMBER
 ,P_IMPUESTO NUMBER
 ) RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
    RETURN (P_IMPORTE*P_IMPUESTO)/100;
END;
```